# Images aren't displaying from XML to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image

I am trying to get an image to display in the table below, the image isn't displaying instead just the URL to the image is. Below is the what I have put into the HTML file. I have copied it off another site and also do not want the push button option and I am not sure how to get rid of that.

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="demo"></table>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
    <br><br>
        <script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "amateur.xml", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;

      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
     var img = document.createElement("img");
      var table="<tr><th>Rating</th><th>Title</th><th>Thumbnail</tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        document.write(img.src);
    document.body.appendChild(img)"</td></tr>";;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
    </script>

        </div>
```

This is a sample of what the XML file looks like, it has been edited slightly as it is inappropriate for the content to be shown. The XML file is called "amateur.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<videos>
<video id="1fb853907b9ca6add9ac">
<url>a.com</url>
<categories>A</categories>
<rating>100</rating>
<title>A</title>
<tags>A;a;AB</tags>
<duration>15</duration>
<thumbnail>http://i1.cdn2a.image.phncdn.com/m=eGcE8daaaa/videos/201011/03/148553/original/12.jpg</thumbnail>

</video>
<video id="d95ebc6a75c00d9926e7">
<url>http://ab.com</url>
<categories>A;B;An</categories>
<rating>100</rating>
<title>Sie spritzt ab</title>
<tags>a;b;as;d</tags>
<duration>65</duration>
<thumbnail>http://i0.cdn2a.image..phncdn.com/m=eGcE8daaaa/videos/201102/17/160998/original/12.jpg</thumbnail>
</video>

</videos>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting in your console, as this `document.body.appendChild(img)"</td></tr>";;` is invalid javascript ... and this `document.write(img.src);` should not be in the code at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is there a `document.write(img.src)`? Normally, you use that when you put it in into an `<img>` tag but then you don't need to create the image object, like:

```
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    var img = x[i].getElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td><img src='"+img+"'></td></tr>";
  }
```

Comment: I love you so much, like i want to kiss you. Do you know how to get to display on open not when you click a button?

Comment: hehe np ;)
of course, put that above your loadXMLDoc():

    (function() {
        loadXMLDoc();
    })();

and remove the double semikolon ;; from the other script, i just forgot to delete it, now i edited the post

Comment: np ;) oh i just saw that now you of course you don't need create the img element, so i adjusted here: https://jsfiddle.net/cuLxbtnt/1/

Comment: Is there away that I am able to href the images?

Comment: I want to so when the user clicks on the image it takes them to the video

Comment: Do you know how to do that or not?

Comment: that's quite simple: https://jsfiddle.net/cuLxbtnt/2/
you should study the code and try to understand how the code work.

Comment: None of the images are displaying now

Comment: Thank you so much, just one more question. Is there a way because there are 10000 videos, is there a way that i can only have 12 on this page and then it automatically make enough pages for the rest of them?

Comment: hmm there are several ways to solve that but in any kind it needs some work. https://www.datatables.net/ may help

Comment: Is there any way that you could help me, I have no idea